# How to format data bound text in a label

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a label control that is bound to a object collection like

```
 lblUser.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", UserCollection, "UserName"));
```

This works fine and the Username on the label. But I need to display the Username as 
**User Name : UserName**

How do I add the static "User Name :" part in front of the bound value on the label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did is that I created a custom label by extending the Label class and added an override to the text property. And added this to the text property

```
set{ Text = "User name :" + value }
get { return value;}
```

This solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use two labels, one for the "User Name:" part, and another that contains the bound name. This way you avoid overcomplicating things. In addition, this can help greatly when you're trying to correctly align multiple label values, making your form look better.

If you must use formatting to do it (in particular interest when binding DateTime values), take a look at the [Binding.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx) event to provide your own format.